# Apache rewrite empty regex (root)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, document-root

I've got Apache 2.4.4 running on Windows 8 laptop (WAMP server) and I found a really odd behavior of .htaccess mod_rewrite rules.

I want to redirect the root of my website to a specific file. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule $^ /static/home.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works only if **there's no index.php file in root directory**. When I create index.php file, Apache redirects empty path straight to the index file and doesn't bother with the first RewriteRule.

Is there a way to have both these RewriteRules and index.php file working together? In oher words, my example works but I want to rename `router.php` to `index.php` and keep both RewriteRules working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just tweak your regex pattern to work in both situation:

```
DirectoryIndex something-else.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /static/home.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Yep, that could do it. Unfortunately I cannot use it because I might have oversimplified my example. I need other URLs handled by index.php file (router of my website). I'm gonna update my question. Do you know why Apache does this?

Comment: I will wait for your edit to suggest you some possible workaround

Comment: Well, this doesn't work but if I change `DirectoryIndex index.php` to `DirectoryIndex something-else.php`, it works. Thanks, I didn't know about the DirectoryIndex!

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: yeah, if you fix the example to work as I wrote, then I'll mark your answer as a solution